# Facebook sharer: Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

Facebook share doesn't work for some URLs from my site.

The Facebook Opengraph debugger gives me the following "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped" on this URL: http://geektimes.ru/post/241334/

But with this URL is OK: http://geektimes.ru/post/241330/

I can see both requests in server logs. Every request processed fine, but problem exists. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer from Facebook support team:

> The issue is originally caused by using a protocol relative url in og:image... Fix the url and you'll see this error go away.

This worked for me.

Comment: How did you fix this image issue?